# System.Timers.Timer и GUI

Tags: c#, gui

Имеется простое приложение WinForms. В окне компонент ListBox, в который периодически должен добавляться элемент. Также выводится периодически MessageBox. Делается с помощью System.Timers.Timer.

```
namespace TestWindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        private int i = 0;
        delegate void GUIUpdate(int numb);

        void DoGUIUpdateListBox(int n)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                GUIUpdate d = new GUIUpdate(this.DoGUIUpdateListBox);
                this.BeginInvoke(d, n);
            }
            else listBox1.Items.Add(n);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Text = "Нажмите, чтобы начать";
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("i = " + i + "\r\n" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond,
   "Timer Event Raised!");
            DoGUIUpdateListBox(i);

            i++;
        }
        private bool begin = false;
        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!begin)
            {
                begin = true;
                button1.Text = "Закончить добавление";
                timer.AutoReset = true;
                timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                begin = false;
                button1.Text = "Начать добавление";
                timer.Stop();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Но обработчик таймера вызывает только Message.Show, а дальше не работает, элементы не отображаются, переменная не инкрементируется, как сделать правильно?

Comment: У меня все работает, но работает правильно только если нажимать на ОК на MessageBox`e

Comment: мне надо, чтобы, например, все выполнялось синхронно

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "синхронно" в данном случае.Если вам просто нужно чтобы в любом случае вызывалось DoGUIUpdateListBox(i) и инкрементилась переменная, то посмотрите мой ответ, если нет, то объясните пожалуйста детальнее.

Comment: да. именно так как у вас в примере. собственно месседжбоксы не нужны, мне нужно просто добавлять в ListBox элементы. но решил добавить MessageBox и вот. Почему так происходит? Вызов MessageBox'a уводит один из потоков таймера на показ окна и там останавливается?

Comment: Каждый вызов MessageBox.Show создает новый поток и ждет пока пользователь примет решение (примет/закроет).

Answer (score 1):

```
    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoGUIUpdateListBox(i);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("i = " + i++ + "\r\n" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond,
   "Timer Event Raised!");

           // i++;
        }
```

Перенес  `DoGUIUpdateListBox(i);` перед вызовом `Messagebox` и сделал i++ внутри вызова  `MessageBox.Show` и все работает нормально

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит из-за того, что Вы обращаетесь к форме из другого потока, можно поправить через Invoke:

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("i = " + i + "\r\n" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond,
   "Timer Event Raised!");
            Invoke(new Action(()=>{DoGUIUpdateListBox(i);});

            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Ваш пример работает аналогично методу автора. Пока не будет закрыто диалоговое окно MessageBox`a, дальше вызова              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show не зайдет.

Comment: Не правильно понял значит. Я думал что очевидно что мессадж бокс не ассинхронный. можно тогда инвок воткнуть на мессадж бокс:

    Invoke(new Action(()=>{System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("i = " + i + "\r\n" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond,"Timer Event Raised!");}));

просто если поточные проблемы возникают, то он тихо их проглотит, не будет ексепшен выкидывать(точнее выкинит, но это прибёт поток и никто об этом не узнает :-) )

Comment: так, это тоже не срабатывает. И вроде я в DoGUIUpdateListBox работаю через BeginInvoke.

Comment: `else listBox1.Items.Add(n);` - это же не через инвок а в потоке таймера выполняется....

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вызов `MessageBox` — блокирующий, поэтому метод `timer_Elapsed` ждёт, пока вы не закроете диалог.

Ваш код избыточно сложен для такой простой задачи. Чтобы не возиться с `InvokeRequired`, примените нативный [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
int n = 0;
timer.Tick += (o, args) => listBox1.Items.Add(n++);
timer.Start();
```